# overloaded method value + with alternatives

Tags: scala

I am new to scala, I am trying to create a list with my existing list.

my current list

```
val votesByLang: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,Seq[(String, Int)]] = Map(pythom -> List((pythom,10)), scala -> List((scala,1), (scala,10), (scala,1)), java -> List((java,4)))

votesByLang.map{
  case (witch,counts) => (witch,counts.foldLeft(0)((x,y)=>x+y))
}.toSeq
```

This gives the an error :

```
      <console>:13: error: overloaded method value + with alternatives:
      (x: Int)Int <and>
      (x: Char)Int <and>
      (x: Short)Int <and>
      (x: Byte)Int
      cannot be applied to ((String, Int))
      votesByLang.map{case (witch,counts)=>(witch,counts.foldLeft(0) ((x,y)=>x+y))}.toSeq
```

but if I use _ for any the same works fine and yeilds result

```
votesByLang.map{
  case (witch,counts) => (witch,counts.foldLeft(0)((_+_._2)))
}.toSeq
```

result:
Seq[(String, Int)] = Vector((pythom,10), (scala,12), (java,4))

What is wrong with the first approach

Comment: You're missing the `_2` in the first version (which returns the `Int` in `(String, Int)`).

Comment: Yes you are right so the first object x is a accumulator and the second is the list of numbers so votesByLang.map{case (witch,counts)=>(witch,counts.foldLeft(0)((x:Int,y)=>x+y._2))}.toSeq

Comment: @Marth  in our map function counts is the Int and we are calling the foldLeft on counts so ideally it the y variable should be an Int not a List right?

Comment: `y` is not a `List` but a tuple `(String, Int)` (see the type of the `Seq` (the values in the `Map`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Marth Suggested the below works.

```
 votesByLang.map{
 case (witch,counts)=>(witch,counts.foldLeft(0)((x:Int,y)=>x+y._2))}.toSeq
```